# Is Spring Batch appropriate for my service code?

Tags: java, spring, spring-batch

From a high level, my application flow looks like

REST Controller RequestMapping is triggered by a GET() request.  REST Controller calls a method in a Service class.

```
@RequestMapping(value="/eventreports", method = RequestMethod.POST, produces = "application/json")
public @ResponseBody List<EventReports> addReportIds(@RequestBody List<Integer> reportIds) {
    List<EventReports> eventReports = railAgentCollectorServiceImpl.addReportIds(reportIds);
    return eventReports;

}
```

Service method calls a methodin a DAO class.

```
@Override
public List<EventReports> addReportIds(List<Integer> reportIds) {

    List<EventReports> eventReports = eventReportsDAOImpl.listEventReportsInJsonRequest(reportIds);
    return eventReports;
}
```

DAO method executes a StoredProcedureQuery against a SQL datasource that returns results as an ArrayList of domain objects.  Service class passes this Arraylist of domain objects back to REST Controller, which returns the ArrayList of domain objects as a JSON string.

```
@Override
public List<EventReports> listEventReportsInJsonRequest(List<Integer> reportIds) {

    ArrayList<EventReports> erArr = new ArrayList<EventReports>();
    try {
        StoredProcedureQuery q = em.createStoredProcedureQuery("sp_get_event_reports", "eventReportsResult");
        q.registerStoredProcedureParameter("reportIds", String.class, ParameterMode.IN);
        q.setParameter("reportIds", reportIdsList);
        boolean isResultSet = q.execute(); //try catch here
        erArr = (ArrayList<EventReports>) q.getResultList();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("No event reports found for list " + reportIdsList);
    }

    return erArr;
}
```

I've been investigating integrating Spring Batch processing into the above pattern.  I've been looking at the Spring getting started guide for batch processing here https://spring.io/guides/gs/batch-processing/ - paying particular attention to the source code for BatchConfiguration.java - I'm uncertain whether my application is suited for Spring Batch, maybe my imcomplete knowledge of Spring Batch and the various ways it can be implemented is preventing me from conceptualizing it.  The BatchConfiguration.java code below suggests to me that Spring Batch may be best suited to iterate through a list of items, read them one by one, process them one by one, and write them one by one - whereas my service code is based on gathering and and writing a list of objects all at once.

```
@Bean
public FlatFileItemReader<Person> reader() {
    FlatFileItemReader<Person> reader = new FlatFileItemReader<Person>();
    reader.setResource(new ClassPathResource("sample-data.csv"));
    reader.setLineMapper(new DefaultLineMapper<Person>() {{
        setLineTokenizer(new DelimitedLineTokenizer() {{
            setNames(new String[] { "firstName", "lastName" });
        }});
        setFieldSetMapper(new BeanWrapperFieldSetMapper<Person>() {{
            setTargetType(Person.class);
        }});
    }});
    return reader;
}

@Bean
public PersonItemProcessor processor() {
    return new PersonItemProcessor();
}

@Bean
public JdbcBatchItemWriter<Person> writer() {
    JdbcBatchItemWriter<Person> writer = new JdbcBatchItemWriter<Person>();
    writer.setItemSqlParameterSourceProvider(new BeanPropertyItemSqlParameterSourceProvider<Person>());
    writer.setSql("INSERT INTO people (first_name, last_name) VALUES (:firstName, :lastName)");
    writer.setDataSource(dataSource);
    return writer;
}
// end::readerwriterprocessor[]

// tag::jobstep[]
@Bean
public Job importUserJob(JobCompletionNotificationListener listener) {
    return jobBuilderFactory.get("importUserJob")
            .incrementer(new RunIdIncrementer())
            .listener(listener)
            .flow(step1())
            .end()
            .build();
}

@Bean
public Step step1() {
    return stepBuilderFactory.get("step1")
            .<Person, Person> chunk(10)
            .reader(reader())
            .processor(processor())
            .writer(writer())
            .build();
}
```

Is this true?  Could I still take advantage of resume-ability, scheduling and synchronization provided by Spring Batch for my existing code? Any suggestions appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I think the main thing that you need to consider this synchronous behavior and asynchronous behavior. Batch process are used for long running tasks, So,

Consider your task it long running or not. If your task is long running you can use batch. This is going to be asynchronous because, your request come in and start the task and then respond back to the user.

And the batch will run and complete and write a result back to the database, User will have to either poll for the result using ajax or you may have to implement push notification mechanism to handle the state of the task for the asynchronous behavior/ prevent polling.

Comment: Yes this task could be long running as sometimes the Json array that is returned by my rest controller can have tens of thousands of rows.  The stored procedure called by my DAO method can return tens of thousands of rows.  Also one thing I forgot to mention is that I am calling this method with an asynchronous rest request - so I am already dealing with the response as a Future object in another service that calls the methods in my rest controller.

Answer (score 0):

Its true that a Spring Batch chunk consisting of a **reader -> processor -> writer** reads one item, processes one item but **writes a chunk of items** according to defined chunk size.

So you can send thousand of items in one go to writer to write to storage depending on your defined **chunk_size**.

Having said that, a reader reads one item but its not necessary to read only one item **from source(from file/DB etc)** itself. There are readers which can read a large quantity of items **in one go from source**, hold it in itself in a list and hand over one by one to processor till list is exhausted.

One such reader is [JdbcPagingItemReader](http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/apidocs/org/springframework/batch/item/database/JdbcPagingItemReader.html) so e.g. it reads few thousand rows from database in one go as per defined reader **page_size** ( that reduces DB calls significantly ) and then keep handing over one by one to processor and then processor automatically keep accumulating processed outputs till **chunk_size** is reached and then hands over to writer in bulk.

Its just another case that something might not be ready off the shelf for your requirement in API - in that case, you will have to write your own `ItemReader`.

Look at the code of `JdbcPagingItemReader` to get ideas.

For your situation, writer of Spring Batch doesn't seem a problem at all, it already writes in bulk with just a simple configuration. You will have to feed Controller's output to reader which works on similar lines as `JdbcPagingItemReader`.

All I want to say that in-memory processing is one by one ( and that is very fast ) but IO can be done in bulk in spring batch ( if you choose so).

Hope it helps !!